# vue multiselect - cannot clear or edit data saved from local storage

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I have stored the multiple selected values into the local storage to persist data just in case if the user refreshes the page.

Now when I retrieve and populate the multiselect. I can no longer edit or change the values in on the multiselect.

Here is the code:

```
<multiselect v-model="formData.daysAvailable" @select="selectedValue" :options="days" :multiple="true"
                                 placeholder="Select the days you can work in"
                                 id="daysAvailable"
                                 :class="hasError('daysAvailable') ? 'is-invalid' : ''"
                                 track-by="name" label="name">
                    </multiselect>

methods: {
openStorage () {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('applicant_form'))
            },
            saveStorage (form) {
                localStorage.setItem('applicant_form', JSON.stringify(form))
            },
 updateForm (input, value) {
                this.formData[input] = value
                let storedForm = this.openStorage()
                if (!storedForm) storedForm = {}
                storedForm[input] = value
                this.saveStorage(storedForm)
            },
selectedValue(value) {

                let storedForm = this.openStorage()
                
                if (storedForm['daysAvailable'].length)  {
                    if (Array.isArray(storedForm['daysAvailable'])) {
                        value =  storedForm['daysAvailable'].push(value)
                    } else {
                        value = [ storedForm['daysAvailable'], value]
                    }
                }
                this.updateForm('daysAvailable', value)
            }
},
 mounted() {
            this.getInternalData()
            const storedForm = this.openStorage()
            if (storedForm) {
                this.formData = {
                    ...this.formData,
                    ...storedForm
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.
selectedValue(value, key) {

```
            let storeValue = [];
            let storedForm = this.openStorage()

            if (storedForm.hasOwnProperty(key))  {
               storeValue = storedForm[key];
                storeValue.push(value);
            } else {

                storeValue.push(value)
            }

            this.updateForm(key, storeValue)
        },
```